# Como encontrar una palabra dentro de una cadena con una Expresión Regular

Tags: javascript, regex

estoy intentando buscar una expresión regular que me ayude a buscar una palabra dentro de una cadena que esta unida por guiones bajos, como en este ejemplo:

string = "EMPRESA_CAPTURA_CLIENTE"

y la palabra que quiero encontrar en esa cadena es CAPTURA, he probado con esta expresión regular:

var patternExclud = /_captura\b/i;

pero siempre me da false.

Comment: ¿Por qué con regex? Puedes usar `cadena.includes(subcadena)`

Comment: Pero en el caso que la cadena llegue en algún momento en minúsculas, daría false, no?

Comment: eso son requerimientos que debes añadir a la pregunta

Comment: En eso tienes razón pero habría que añadir mas lineas de código, con una Expresión regular correcta he conseguido mediante el método test() obtener un boleano que puedo usar, como la Expresión regular también hace una comparativa entre mayusculas y minúsculas, gracias al flag de /i, esa parte no tengo que comprobarla, muchas gracias por la respuesta para mi ha sido la mas eficiente, ;)

Answer (score 1):

Al final la Expresion regular correcta era la siguiente:

```
var patternExclud = /captura/i
```

De esa manera y utilizando el método test obtenemos un booleano.
Esto quedaría de esta manera:

```js
var cadena = "EMPRESA_CAPTURA_CLIENTE"
var patternExclud = /captura/i;
var resultPattern = patternExclud.test(cadena);

console.log(resultPattern);
```

Muchas Gracias por la ayuda, muy buenas respuestas.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#ejemplosearch').on('keyup keypress change', function(){

    /**VALOR DEL INPUT SEARCH, CAMPO BUSCAR*/
    var dtsearch = $('#ejemplosearch').val();


    /***ESTE VALOR PUEDE SER UN DATO TRAIDO DESDE UNA BD ATRAVEZ DE AJAX */
    var dtbd="EMPRESA_CAPTURA_CLIENTE"

    /*** EVALUAMOS EL VALOR A BUSCAR CON EL DT DE LA BD O EN ESTE CASO EL QUE TENGO ASIGNADO
     * CON indexOf se busca una cadena que coincida con la del valor del input #ejemplosearch,
     * con toLowerCase convierte ambas cadenas a minusculas, es decir no importa si se busca en mayuscula y en la
     * bd esta en minusucula o en caso contrario siempre buscara esa coincidencia
     */
    let result = dtbd.toLowerCase().indexOf(dtsearch.toLowerCase());

    /*** esa comparacion te aroja -1 si no encuentra coincidencia, o un valor diferente si encuentra al menos una coincidencia
     *
     */
    if(result !== -1){
        console.log(dtsearch,"SE ENCONTRO UNA CONCIDENCIA CON: ", dtbd);
       
    }else{
        console.log(dtsearch,"NO SE ENCONTRO CONCIDENCIA CON: ", dtbd);
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EJEMPLO</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="text" name="searchdb" id="ejemplosearch">
   
  
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

AGREGUE CASO DE PRUEBA DONDE EXPLICO MI EJEMPLO, ESPERO QUE TE SIRVA.

Comment: Muy muy buena tu respuesta, buscaba una solución mas cómoda con un expresión regular, que al final con los métodos que se pueden utilizar se puede obtener una respuesta sobre ese string. De todas formas muchas gracias y te agradezco tu script que me ha parecido super interesante.

Comment: de nada bro, en realida es más facil hacerlo con indexOf(), que con una expresion regular, las expresion regular seria para algo más especifico, pero como tu busqueda es general se puede hacer de esta manera, de hecho esa misma funcion la uso para hacer busquedas por palabras claves, y si te sirvio no olvides marcar la respuesta como valida.